# XML web Service

Tags: asp.net, xml, web-services, apache-flex, air

iam using adobe flex and connects it to XML web Service(asp.net) 
now the situation is like this
Sometimes i send large data on to the web service ,the data reaches correctly to the web service and the web service starts to save it in an SQL server database ,in some cases the connection with the web service is lost -but that does not mean that the web service stops processing the data couse the data is already there 
my problem is that the web service continues to work and flex is giving me everything is ok , so when i send another time a duplication happens
so is there a way on FLEX or asp.net to check is the connection (not internet connection ) is still valid and if its lost during the processing to cancel it

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your server process, you can add a remote validation method to see if it started working and how far through it has gone.

For example, if you requested 80 calculations and it timed out, you can call a different server-side method from Flex to check in the database for registers of calculations completed. If only 46 of them have been done, you can display a completion rate in your client of 46/80 = 57.5%